# Since update to Xcode 7 and iOS 9, UICollectionView freezes the app

Tags: ios9, xcode7

We have a UICollectionView embedded in a UIViewController using a Container and using Storyboard.

When the app loads and the collection view is trying to load. The app freezes without any warnings or errors!

The same code has been working in iOS 8 and Xcode 6. The production version of the app with the same code works with iOS 9, too.

Have you had a similar problem? Or do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I have tried, the followings: using Swift instead of Objective-C, Reproducing all the collection view again, not embedding the collection view in a container view. None of these had any effects! Sometimes it even caused a new error of "XPC connection interrupted"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly, the issue was in TextView and ImageView under the custom UICollectionViewCell, which were working correctly before updating to Xcode 7!

I recreated the TextView and ImageView and the issue fixed! I am still not sure what caused the issue after the update.

Answer (score 0):

My team has been struggling with this same issue since upgrading to XCode 7 last week.  In our case, we were disabling user interaction whenever we displayed an activity view:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
```

Then, in a callback block we were re-enabling user interaction with this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
```

Removing these calls resolved three out of four of these issues in our code; hopefully it can fix your issue as well.  In any event, we haven't come up with a better approach as of yet.

This code worked fine in iOS 6, 7 and 8 but for some reason its not working in iOS 9.  The iOS 9 release notes don't mention anything about this, and the method is not marked as `deprecated` so we are not sure exactly what is going on.  We are guessing Apple changed something under the hood to enforce some rule more strictly, so maybe a shortcut we were able to get away with in the past is no longer working.  If anyone has any thoughts as to why this is happening we would very much like to hear them so we can understand the issue better.